# Django template tag if doesn't compare as expected

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

Django version: `$ python -m django --version`:
3.1.2

My template contains this form:

```
        <form method="post">
        {% for samtalepartner in elev %}
            <input type="radio" 
                   name="elev" 
                   id="elev{{ forloop.counter  }}" 
                   value="{{ samtalepartner.id }}">
            <label for="elev{{ forloop.counter  }}">
                {{ samtalepartner.id }}{{ request.POST.elev }} 
                {% if samtalepartner.id == request.POST.elev %}
                <b>{{ samtalepartner.fulde_navn }}</b>
                {% else %}
                {{ samtalepartner.fulde_navn }}
                {% endif %}
            </label>
            <br>
        {% endfor %}
        <input type="submit" value="Fremhæv valgte">
        </form>
```

When I submit first time the browser shows:

```
1 Andersine Andersen
2 Sida Dida
```

When selecting #2 and submitting again, I expected, as `2==2`:

```
12 Andersine Andersen
22 <b>Sida Dida </b>
```

However, browser shows:

```
12 Andersine Andersen
22 Sida Dida
```

How come that the two values do not compare and executes the `{% if %}` statement
(rather than the `{% else %}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the problem is that `request.POST.elev` is a `string` and `samtalepartner.id` is an `int`. So try to convert it to `string`:

```
{% if samtalepartner.id|slugify == request.POST.elev %}
```

Comment: Surprising name for the `slugify`filter with the function of converting integer into string. And [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#slugify) is not explicit about this. That explains why my search did not produce the result, @neverwalkaloner provided.